# I want to move semantics but I get a universal reference which hides copy semantics

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

How can I deal with universal reference, when I want either to copy semantics with a function parameter `const T&` or move semantics with function parameter `T&&`. The later hides the first.

A sample code with algebraic vector operators follow.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
void neg(T &a) { for (auto &i : a) i = -i; }

// object 'a' remains available
template<typename T>
auto operator-(const T &a) { std::cout << "1\r\n"; T b = a; neg(b); return b; }

// object 'a' terminates its life
template<typename T>
auto operator-(T &&a) { std::cout << "2\r\n"; neg(a); return std::move(a); }

// make an rvalue
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const T1 &a, const T2 &b) { return a; }


int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a;
    auto d = -(a+a);        // outputs 2 : correct
    auto e = -a;            // outputs 2 : I want 1
    auto f = -std::move(a); // outputs 2 : correct
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** One of the solutions proposed by **user17732522** (please upvote him).

```
template<typename T>
auto operator-(T &&a)
{
    std::cout << "2\r\n"; neg(a); return std::move(a);
}
template<typename T>
auto operator-(T &a)
{
    std::cout << "1\r\n";
    std::remove_cvref_t<T> b = a;
    neg(b); return b;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a;
    auto d = -(a+a);        // now outputs 2 : correct
    auto e = -a;            // now outputs 1 : correct
    auto f = -std::move(a); // now outputs 2 : correct
    const std::array<int, 4> b{1,2,3,4};
    d = -(b+b);     // now outputs 2 : correct
    e = -b;         // now outputs 1 : correct
    return 0;
}
```

Another solution, always based on **user17732522** answer, is this:

```
template<typename T>
requires(!std::is_reference_v<T>)
auto operator-(T &&a);

template<typename T>
auto operator-(const T &a);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove `const` from `const T&`.

With `using U = std::array<int, 4>;`:

The issue here is that `T&&` deduces `T` to `U`, not `const U`, since `a` in `main` isn't `const`. And binding to `U&` instead of `const U&` is considered better in overload resolution.

If you remove `const` from `const T&`, then both candidates will after deduction have a function parameter `U&` and consequently neither will be better based on that.

However, in partial ordering of function templates the `T&` template will win over `T&&` and so the former will be chosen if the function argument is a lvalue.

This does however have the consequence that `a` in the function will not be `const` qualified. You can obtain a `const` reference from it by applying `std::as_const`.

Alternatively you can use a `requires` clause or `std::enable_if` to constrain the `T&&` template on `T` being a non-reference type. Or you can use a single function template and decide in its body how to operate based on the type of the reference with `if constexpr`. Relevant type traits: `std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>` or `std::is_reference_v<T>` and `std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(a)>`.